# Increase font size for Unity3D on linux (Or scaling the UI)

Tags: linux, fonts

I have tried many things but seems like the only way to make the Unity GUI bigger on linux is by changing the GTK scale which can be only integers... Problem is that multiplying everything by 2 is too much for me.

Does anyone happen to know any workaround for making Unity usable in HiDPI/Linux ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to follow my approach in the Unity Forums;
(it is about changing the Display Resolution in an Bash / Terminal, for using Unity3D... and when you have finished using the Software, the Original Resolution would be restore to its original value):

https://forum.unity.com/threads/editor-ui-scaling.721424/#post-7079464

Comment: Oh yeah i came up with the same solution. I already had this for other software that just displays too small. I created a shortcut that runs: `[ -e /tmp/scalelockfile  ] && (xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1x1; rm /tmp/scalelockfile) || (xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale .75x.75; touch /tmp/scalelockfile)` toggling between the two resolutions.

Comment: I am glad you got to solve the issue.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a solution. I think the true solution will be when the scaling option that exists on windows comes to linux. I am not very hopeful that will happen anytime soon though.